# Entity Framework 6 ошибка DTO - "has no key"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dto

Сделал модель:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Server.DB 
{   
    [Serializable]
    [Table("users")]
    public class UserDTO : AbstractDto {
        [Key]
        public UInt32 ID { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Nick { get; set; }    
    }   
}
```

далее, код коннектора:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using MySql.Data.Entity;

namespace Server.DB {

    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class EntityContext : DbContext, IEntityContext {

        public EntityContext() : base("name=DBConnector") { }

        public DbSet<UserDTO> Users { get; set; }

    }

}
```

При попытке простого Select-а:

```
var query = UnitOfWorkFactory.Instance.Get.EntityContext.Set<UserDTO>().AsQueryable();
UserDTO user = query.Where(q => q.Login == "test@test.ru" && q.Password == "1234").ToList()[0];
```

Получаю исключение:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException" в EntityFramework.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Server.DB.DataAccess.UserDTO: : EntityType 'UserDTO' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> Users: EntityType: EntitySet 'Users' is based on type 'UserDTO' that has no keys defined.

Подскажите, в чём ошибка, и как можно заставить EF6 посмотреть на схему?
С EF6 до этого не работал.

---

## **Добавлено**

Делаю миграцию, получаю следующее исключение:

> PM> Enable-Migrations -ProjectName SqlDbAPI -StartUpProjectName OGameServer -ContextTypeName Server.DB.EntityContext -Verbose -Force
>
> Using StartUp project 'OGameServer'.
>   Checking if the context targets an existing database...
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(String providerTypeName, String providerInvariantName)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__2(ProviderElement e)
>      в System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator 2.MoveNext()
>      в System.Collections.Generic.List 1..ctor(IEnumerable 1 collection)
>      в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable 1 source)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__1()
>      в System.Lazy 1.CreateValue()
>      в System.Lazy 1.LazyInitValue()
>      в System.Lazy 1.get_Value()
>      в System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DbProviderServices()
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices()
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple 2 t)
>      в System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary 2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func 2 valueFactory)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
>      в System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator 2.MoveNext()
>      в System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable 1 source, Func 2 predicate)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver 2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
>      в System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
>      в System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
>      в Server.DB.EntityContext..ctor() в G:\Sources\MinGW\QuickStart\OGame\Server\SqlDbAPI\DBMySql\EntityContext.cs:строка 11
>   --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
>      в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()
>      в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func 1 resolver)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>      в System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>      в System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>      в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>
> `The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.`

Comment: @DenisBubnov, Код абстрактного класса - пустой. Убирать его из наследования пробовал - ни на что не влияет

Comment: Кстати, пообщался с человеком, он намекнул на то что связанно это может быть с MySQL, и тем что я создал все таблицы руками (я то надеялся на поведение как у хибера).

Comment: Ах руками...да, тогда вы сделали что-то не так 

Comment: @DenisBubnov, делаю миграцию, если получится - отпишусь, если нет... в любом случае отпишусь)

Comment: @DenisBubnov, как бы не так, практика показывает что руки для шарпа у меня кривые XD не могу понять, почему оно валится... Вроде оба проекта указал, сущность базы тоже, а всё равно не хочет генерировать ничего...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был найден совершенно СЛУЧАЙНО. Никакая миграция не помогла, более того, процесс миграции так же валился с той же злощастной ошибкой об отсутствии первичного ключа. Ошибка была в том, что EF вообще не воспринемает в упор типы UIntXX/uint! Изменение типа ключа на int - исправило все ошибки, и проект запустился без миграции...

Если кто нибудь ответит почему это происходит, буду очень признателен!

Comment: UInt32 - это тот же самый тип, что uint. Они отличаются только в коде (в тексте), после компиляции unit от UInt32 отличить нельзя :). Т.е. неизвестно что у вас там было, но скорее всего типы были ни при чем :)

Comment: @PashaPash, >>но скорее всего типы были ни при чем<< Уже сделал тестовый проект, стабильно не работает с ключами Int32/UInt32. Я понимаю что эти типы должны быть синонимичны int/uint, но, практика показывает что они действительно не работают.

Comment: Да, приврал, тип Int32 всё таки работает, а вот UInt32 не воспринемается.

Comment: Да, судя по всему, EF не поддерживает в качестве ключа uint / UInt32. Только int / Int32. Подправьте ответ, пожалуйста.